# Dual monitor support for ASUS M4A785TD-V EVO

Tags: multiple-monitors

My motherboard is an [ASUS M4A785TD-V EVO](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131398).

It has VGA and DVI onboard and I was wondering if I could hook up a monitor to both and be able to have dual monitor display (one long screen, not two monitors showing the same output).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even better, according to the review "[AMD 785G chipset. ASUS M4A785TD-V motherboard under the spotlight](http://www.hexus.net/content/item.php?item=19568&page=3)", thanks to DVI and HDMI out, "dual digital displays can be driven concurrently", so you don't have to use the analog VGA connector (unless of course you want to use an old CRT monitor).

And in order to get the "one long screen" select the option "Extend my Windows desktop onto this monitor" as opposed to clone mode.

Comment: Oh, I glazed right over the fact that it had HDMI also. Good catch.

Comment: yep, you can probably run a triple monitor setup on ths board without an add-on card.

Comment: Wait, so technically, I could have a triple monitor display? One DVI, one VGA, and one on a big ole flat screen tv or a projector? =D

Comment: @Molly: You sure? That would be awesome if you could. Just need to find a review or someone who has done it. I'm curious how well that built on video card would handle such a setup.

Comment: @Molly: Ok, I could see that working, but on-boards usually have some extra limitations, so that is why I was skeptical. Hmm.

Comment: yes, there is that possibility. i'm driving 3 1920x1200 monitors on a similar graphics card (HD4350, although not onboard) via HDMI & DVI & VGA. if all fails, this card costs around $40 and the board does have a PCIe expansion slot.

Comment: I'm wondering why it was two PCIe slots as well, If I were a millionaire having 7 monitors could be possible (if the triple monitor works and the cards in the PCIe slots support dual output). Ahh.. pipe dreams.. =p

Comment: reading the review at hexus.net, it looks like a decent mainboard and the IGP can take some overclocking. and yes, it supports Crossfire, so you can throw in two graphics cards :)

Comment: @coolryguy:  The 16x PCI-E slots are used for video primarily and the other 4x/8x/1x slots can be used for network cards, wireless, sound, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Most onboard video chipsets only allow one connection to be used at a time.  The multiple ports are there for flexibility. So, you can use either DVI or VGA.

If you would like dual monitors, you most likely will need to pick up a PCI-E video card to add to the computer.  Then you could hook up one monitor to the DVI or VGA of the motherboard and the other monitor to the PCI-E video card.

Just noticed this has HDMI also. Looks like you can on this model with HDMI and DVI/VGA(one or the other)?

Comment: Doesn't using a separate graphics card disable the on-board output? Or am I behind the times?

Comment: @ChrisF:  You can, but with most newer ones I've seen, you can also leave it enabled and use it as second monitor.  You do select which one is default though in the BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

I used my knowledge of the english language reviewed the motherboard specifications, stubled on: Dual independent displays support with HDMI / DVI and D-Sub 
and so the answer is: You could.