# DVI to RCA: Dual Monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have onboard video with DVI and VGA out. Right now I'm using the VGA out to connect to my monitor, but if I buy this: [DVI to RCA cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000Q6RL9Q)
Will I be able to have dual monitor support, one for my current monitor and one for my TV?

I'm looking to watch videos on my tv while I surf the web and stuff on my monitor.

I've already figured out that my motherboard can support dual monitors , as discussed in this thread: [Dual monitor support](https://superuser.com/questions/74522/dual-monitor-support)

#### Edit:

That DVI to RCA cable has some pretty bad reviews... just to clarify, I want to hook the DVI out on my onboard video to a tv like you would connect a game console to a tv

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the picture of your motherboard on the other question, it has a DVI-D connector (digital only; missing the four pins at the side) and *not* a DVI-I (both analogue and digital).

DVI->component-RCA cables like this work on the analogue signal (converting digital to analogue is a much harder task!) so this cable will presumbly **not work** on your setup.

If you could connect your monitor to the DVI (if it's a flatscreen you definitely want to be running it digital anyway), then you could use the VGA to connect to the TV. There are many VGA->3xRCA converters available, both cables and boxes.

Comment: in other words, assuming the motherboard is indeed DVI-D, to do what the OP is asking requires a __signal converter__, not simply a __port adapter__.

Comment: Right, that's what I was thinking. So I could just pick up a DVI male to VGA female adapter and hook up my VGA monitor to that, then get a VGA to RCA cable? TYVM.

Comment: Sadly no, because the (typical) DVI-to-VGA adapter also uses the analogue portion of a DVI-I signal to send to the VGA, and that's the bit you're missing in your DVI-D socket. Essentially you're after two analogue signals (regardless of particular type of connector), but your motherboard only outputs one. You'd need to stick a graphics card in there that can produce 2xAnalogue (VGA or DVI-I), or replace your monitor with a flatpanel that can talk digital (DVI or HDMI).